# How to test IntegrationFlow with FileReadingMessageSource and HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have an integration flow to poll json files from some folder and send them to a rest http endpoint. Below my code:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jsonFileToRestFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("fileInputChannel")
            .transform(new FileToStringTransformer())
            .enrichHeaders(s -> s.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf8"))
            .handle(httpRequestExecutingMessageHandler())
            .get();
}
```

After receiving response from `http` endpoint i will move my files to successful or failure channel. Now i want to test my code. What is the best way to test this code. My idea is to put some `json` Files in my `inputChannel` and then mock my http response and check if expected message is in `successChannel` or failure. But I don't know how to start. Can anyone give me some tips? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, take a look into the [Spring Integration Testing Framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/testing.html#test-context). So, your `httpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` can be replaces with the `MockIntegration.mockMessageHandler()` where you really can produce any possible mocked reply in the `handleNextAndReply()`.

Another option is like a [MockMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework) and its `MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory` to be injected into the `RestTemplate` for the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`.

Success or failure can be achieved with the [`ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice) applied on the `.handle(httpRequestExecutingMessageHandler())` endpoint.